# Validating User Input For a Continuing an Application

Tags: java

I have a validation class that ensures that user input is correct. One of the methods in this class attempts to validate a continue application key word. The user is suppose to be able to enter y or Y to continue and n or N to quit. Any other letter should be answered by a warning messaged followed by another opportunity for the user to input their answer. Here is the code that I have written for the method.

```
public static String getValidContinueCode(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        String choice = "";
        boolean isValid = false;

        while (isValid == false)
        {
        System.out.print(prompt);

        if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            choice = sc.next();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            choice = sc.next();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
        }
        }
        return choice;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from a Scanner with `sc.next()` you consume that character, you can't read it again. You need to store it when you read it and the build your logic around the read value.

```
public static String getValidContinueCode(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    String choice = "";
    boolean isValid = false;

    while (!isValid) {
        System.out.print(prompt);

        choice = sc.next();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
        }
    }
    return choice;

}
```

There are several small improvements you can do. And you probably want to just return a boolean with the answer. Like this.

```
public static boolean getValidContinueCode(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);

        if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    getValidContinueCode(new Scanner(System.in),"");
}

public static void getValidContinueCode(Scanner sc,String code) {
    code = "enter a letter";
    boolean status = true;
    while (status) {
        System.out.println(code);
        String check = sc.next();
        if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            code = "ok";
            status = true;

        } else if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            code = "exit";
            System.out.println("exit");
            status = false;
        } else {
            code = "retry";
            status = true;
        }

    }
}
```